# Route between two branch offices via IPsec VPN to head office?

Tags: vpn, routing, ipsec, microsoft-ftmg-2010

I have TMG 2010 running on Server 2008 R2 in our head office with 2 branch offices connecting in using Dray Tek 2930 routers with IPsec site to site VPNS. The remote sites can route between the head office network and vice versa with no issues. I would like to enable the branch offices to route between each other.

Head Office is on 192.168.100.0/24 DG 192.168.100.254 (internal TMG NIC)

Branch office A is on 192.168.7.0/24 DG 192.168.7.1

Branch office B is on 192.168.0.0/24 DG 192.168.0.1

On the routers at the branch offices I have added the other subnets to the routing table to route via the VPN.
On TMG network and Firewall rules allow traffic between all networks listed above and traffic simulator reports allowed packets.

When pinging from one branch network to the other, TMG Reports that allowed packet from source network to destination network correctly, however pings fail. RDP is the same.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont see a diagram of your network, but I asume that your "link" between your two branch offices is your Head Office, so try to put on your TMG some "permanent routes" to your branches using the TMG gateway. Now when a branch look for the other one it will be bridged by your TMG. **(Sorry my english, is not my common languaje)**